夢中にする vs 夢中になる の違い
「夢中になる」と「夢中にする」のニュアンスと使い方の違いについて教えていただけますか？

They have very different meanings.

夢中になる means "to become crazy/obsessed". 彼女は彼に夢中になった means she became obsessed with him.
夢中にする means "to make someone crazy/obsessed", i.e., to captivate or fascinate someone. 彼女は彼を夢中にした means she captivated him.


Thank you for your reply.
